# Prevent Docker Compose From Creating Default Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My docker-compose file is pasted below. When I run `docker compose up` a default network is created in addition to the two I have defined in the compose file.

My understanding is that docker only creates a default network if there's a service definition that doesn't have a `networks` assigned to it, in which case docker takes that to mean you have the following

```
networks
 - default
```

I'm I missing something? I don't want to have a default network as the default network messes up with the IP ranges on my server and I don't want to have to configure the default network with a custom subnet, that would be the last resort, if there's no way to prevent docker from creating it.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: odoo_image:13.0
    container_name: odoo

    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8069:8069
    volumes:
      - ./odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - customaddons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - enterprise-addons:/mnt/enterprise-addons
    environment:
      - HOST=xxx
      - USER=xxx
      - PASSWORD=xxx
    networks:
      - web
      - db


  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: db

    restart: always
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxx

    networks: 
      - db


# Named Volume Definitions
volumes:
  odoo-db-data:
  odoo-web-data:

  customaddons:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/customaddons'

  enterprise-addons:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/enterprise-addons'


# Network Definitions
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24

  web:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.178.10.0/24
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Could it be a leftover from a previous try ? I suggest you `docker-compose down` your project, then `docker network rm <your_project>_default` if still there, and start again to see if that network is re-created. I'm quite confident it won't be.

Comment: Also note that Compose creates its own network named `default`, which is different from the "default Docker network"; you can [explicitly configure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) to avoid specifying `networks:` for each service.